# Is there anyway to not let user lost focus from winforms in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

**Issue:**
My Question may be weird but I need help with this.
I have this weird problem with my client PC and it all happens sometimes.
The application loses control when I close one form and opens another form.
Then he has to use the mouse and click on the form every time.

**Similar but another issue.**
In an MDI child form, what I do is make the user fill data in a bunch of textboxes and make the user click (or hit Enter Key) that adds that data in a datagridview row and clears all textbox and make focus on the first textbox. 
At that time too the form loses focus and the user is not able to write anything. Though the textbox is still coloured (custom coloured textbox on got focus) but form loses control.

**The Temporary solution:**
-I make his PC restart and everything starts working fine.
-Even Closing the whole application won't help it. I have to restart the PC only.

**MY Code between two forms:**

```
Private Sub btnOk_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnOk.Click
  .... 
  Hide()
  frmUser.Show()
End Sub
```

I use Hide to close 1st form else I use `close()` to switch between forms.
I even face this issue of losing focus in MDI child forms too.

I even made a custom textbox that changes its background colour when it gets focus (in gotfocus event) and reverse to white when loses focus (lost focus event), so when the issue starts the textbox remains coloured and even the cursor blinking inside but I cannot type in it. Again I have to click on the application form (anywhere) and I am able to type again. Until that form closed or changed in the application.

Please help with this weird issue. Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried doing the Hide() after the Show()?  It is a long time ago that I did WinForms, but I seem to remember that this order could be important.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock, I used `hide()` in just 1st form, if I close it the whole application will close as it's the first form. Else everywhere I used `close()`. I from the beginning wrote `hide()` first and then `frmUser.Show()` If you say, I can alter but as I said this happens sometimes and can't catch it what exactly happens. Please read the question again, I added extra info below issue.

Comment: not sure if it helps (or whether this is what you want to achieve), but did you try *frmUser.ShowDialog()*, that makes it modal, thus no other form in your app can be accessed until this one is closed

Comment: @dba I can use modal Dialog on single forms but what do I do in MDI forms.? Possibly modal dialog can do make it force to focus on application.

Comment: to be honest, I wasn't using winforms for a while (I use WPF for UI), so it was just a shot in the dark. :-) But if I read it right, you have Mainform and from this one you open up a child window (and hiding your mainwindow) from a click event or so, right? Can't you call your child window with showdialog? this would block your mainwindow until your child is closed... Maybe you could show more code, and/or a pic of your form(s) layout

Comment: The reason I suggested Show() before Hide() was precisely because it is occasional behaviour.  What may well be happening, is that in the millisecond between hiding the first form and showing the next, the operating system may step in and hand over to another process.   This effect would be totally random.  Reversing the order would ensure that focus passes to the new form, before the first form loses focus.

Comment: @JonathanWillcock, possible but what system does in the 2nd issue I wrote. there isn't any form opening or closing. And yes I'll try that when the issue persists. I know it will happen in near future. I'll try to record the incident this time and put the recorded link here.

Comment: @dba, yes I am thinking for showdialog now. It wont be an issue. But what I do in the 2nd Issue I wrote?

Comment: My guess of what is going on is this. You hide a form that has focus, and then you show a new form which should get the focus. But, in this short period windows can detect your application has nothing focused, so it gives focus to some other application. So you need to keep your application focused during this switch. Its not the problem that your second form did not get focus, the problem is your application looses focus. So I guess you need to make sure that at no time there is nothing focused on your application, or set focus back to your application.

Comment: I wonder, why do you hide the form ? I use winforms alot still and I never closed or hidden a form in code like that. When a user opens a new form, there is no reason for me to close the one that is open now. That is why I probably never had this problem.

Comment: @GuidoG I feel the same but how do I do that. Single forms I can make it modal dialog so it won't lose focus. But what can I do with the MDI Child form? it loses focus when I add data to datagridview. What shall I do for it?

Comment: I use only MDI for my winforms applications, and I do not have this problem. I think it is because you hide your forms, why do you hide forms in a MDI application ? I don't see any need for that

Comment: @GuidoG No, I don't hide any of my forms except 1. And this issue occurs sometimes only and not always and that too in just one client's PC.